# How can I DRY out this F# code? (Fluent Interface)

Tags: f#, xamarin.forms

So this is some of the wettest code I've ever written. But it's useful, which is annoying. The reason for all the repetition is because I want to keep the interface fluent. If I augmented the base class (which happens to be `View` in this case), it would only give back an instance of `View`, which would prevent me from doing something like

```
let label = theme.CreateLabel().WithMargin(new Thickness(5.0)).WithText("Hello")
```

because the `Label.Text` property is not implemented by the `View` base class.

So here is my fluent interface. Get ready. It's ugly, and repetitive. But it also works, and is convenient to use.

Have I missed an obvious way to DRY it out?

```
module ViewExtensions =
    let private withTwoWayBinding<'TElement, 'TProperty, 'TViewModel, 'TView when 'TView :> IViewFor<'TViewModel>>(viewModel: 'TViewModel, view: 'TView, viewModelProperty: Expr<'TViewModel -> 'TProperty>, viewProperty: Expr<'TView -> 'TProperty>) (element: 'TElement) = 
        view.Bind(viewModel, ExpressionConversion.toLinq viewModelProperty, ExpressionConversion.toLinq viewProperty) |> ignore
        element
    let private withHorizontalOptions<'TElement when 'TElement :> View> options (element: 'TElement) =
        element.HorizontalOptions <- options
        element
    let private withVerticalOptions<'TElement when 'TElement :> View> options (element: 'TElement) =
        element.VerticalOptions <- options
        element
    let private withAlignment<'TElement when 'TElement :> View> horizontalOptions verticalOptions (control: 'TElement) =
        control |> withHorizontalOptions horizontalOptions |> withVerticalOptions verticalOptions
    let private withMargin<'TElement when 'TElement :> View> margin (element: 'TElement) = 
        element.Margin <- margin
        element
    let private withActions<'TElement> (actions: ('TElement -> unit)[]) (element: 'TElement) = 
        for action in actions do action(element)
        element
    type Xamarin.Forms.Entry with 
        member this.WithHorizontalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithVerticalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithAlignment(horizontalOptions, verticalOptions) = withAlignment horizontalOptions verticalOptions this
        member this.WithTwoWayBinding(viewModel, view, viewModelProperty, viewProperty) = withTwoWayBinding(viewModel, view, viewModelProperty, viewProperty) this
        member this.WithMargin(margin) = withMargin margin this
        member this.With(actions) = withActions actions this
        member this.With(action: Entry -> unit) = this.With([|action|])
    type Xamarin.Forms.Grid with 
        member this.WithHorizontalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithVerticalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithAlignment(horizontalOptions, verticalOptions) = withAlignment horizontalOptions verticalOptions this
        member this.WithMargin(margin) = withMargin margin this
        member this.With(actions) = withActions actions this
        member this.With(action: Grid -> unit) = this.With([|action|])
    type Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout with 
        member this.WithHorizontalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithVerticalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithAlignment(horizontalOptions, verticalOptions) = withAlignment horizontalOptions verticalOptions this
        member this.WithMargin(margin) = withMargin margin this
        member this.With(actions) = withActions actions this
        member this.With(action: StackLayout -> unit) = this.With([|action|])
    type Xamarin.Forms.Button with 
        member this.WithHorizontalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithVerticalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithAlignment(horizontalOptions, verticalOptions) = withAlignment horizontalOptions verticalOptions this
        member this.WithMargin(margin) = withMargin margin this
        member this.WithText(text) = this.Text <- text; this
        member this.With(actions) = withActions actions this
        member this.With(action: Button -> unit) = this.With([|action|])
    type Xamarin.Forms.Switch with 
        member this.WithHorizontalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithVerticalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithAlignment(horizontalOptions, verticalOptions) = withAlignment horizontalOptions verticalOptions this
        member this.WithTwoWayBinding(viewModel, view, viewModelProperty, viewProperty) = withTwoWayBinding(viewModel, view, viewModelProperty, viewProperty) this
        member this.WithMargin(margin) = withMargin margin this
        member this.With(actions) = withActions actions this
        member this.With(action: Switch -> unit) = this.With([|action|])
    type Xamarin.Forms.Label with 
        member this.WithHorizontalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithVerticalOptions(options) = withHorizontalOptions options this
        member this.WithAlignment(horizontalOptions, verticalOptions) = withAlignment horizontalOptions verticalOptions this
        member this.WithMargin(margin) = withMargin margin this
        member this.WithText(text) = this.Text <- text; this
        member this.With(actions) = withActions actions this
        member this.With(action: Label -> unit) = this.With([|action|])
```

**UPDATE**

So thanks to your help, the answer is yes, I was missing something obvious. As TheQuickBrownFox explained, if I change the fluent interface to something of the form

```
let label = theme.CreateLabel() |> withMargin(new Thickness(5.0)) |> withContent("Hello")
```

then the monster you see above can be replaced in its entirety by

```
module ViewExtensions =
    let withTwoWayBinding<'TElement, 'TProperty, 'TViewModel, 'TView when 'TView :> IViewFor<'TViewModel>>(viewModel: 'TViewModel, view: 'TView, viewModelProperty: Expr<'TViewModel -> 'TProperty>, viewProperty: Expr<'TView -> 'TProperty>) (element: 'TElement) = 
        view.Bind(viewModel, ExpressionConversion.toLinq viewModelProperty, ExpressionConversion.toLinq viewProperty) |> ignore
        element
    let withHorizontalOptions options (element: #View) = element.HorizontalOptions <- options; element
    let withVerticalOptions options (element: #View) = element.VerticalOptions <- options; element
    let withAlignment horizontalOptions verticalOptions element = element |> withHorizontalOptions horizontalOptions |> withVerticalOptions verticalOptions
    let withMargin margin (element: #View) = element.Margin <- margin; element
    let withCaption text (element: #Button) = element.Text <- text; element
    let withText text (element: #Entry) = element.Text <- text; element
    let withContent text (element: #Label) = element.Text <- text; element
    let withSetUpActions<'TElement> (actions: ('TElement -> unit)[]) (element: 'TElement) = (for action in actions do action(element)); element
    let withSetUpAction<'TElement> (action: 'TElement -> unit) = withSetUpActions([|action|])
```

This code deletion is very pleasing indeed.

Comment: Can't you do postfix application (aka "pipe forward") instead of extension methods? That way you could make the functions generic with constraints.

Comment: I have to admit, I wasn't quite sure what you meant until I read TheQuickBrownFox's answer. It makes perfect sense now. And it works very nicely. Update pending.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idiomatic F# approach to fluent interfaces is just to use the pipe forward operator `|>`

```
module ViewHelpers
    let withMargin margin element = ...
    let withText text element = ...

open ViewHelpers

let label = theme.CreateLabel() |> withMargin (new Thickness(5.0)) |> withText "Hello"
```

I think you can also shorten your function signatures using [flexible types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/flexible-types-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
let withMargin margin (element: #View) = ...
```

Comment: This sounds great. I'll get round to trying it out ASAP and mark this as the answer if all goes well. As happens so often with F#, I'm learning all the time. Flexible types are a brilliant idea, and I'd never heard of them until now.